# Java Dictionary value of type tuple

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary

I want a Dictionary (HashTable, Map, ...) that has one key and several values.

I.e. I want something like

`HashTable<Key, [value1, value2]>`

How do I get this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way I think:

```
Map<Key, List<Value>>
```

If you would rather just have a tuple (pair, 3, or ...) you can create a `Pair` class.

```
class Pair<E,F, ...> {

    public E one;
    public F two;
    ...

}
```

And then use a `Map` like so:

```
Map<Key, Pair<Value, Value>>
```

Comment: okay, I thought there was another solution. Since I'm new to Java I thought there might be a data structure that supports this.

Comment: @pitik, I don't believe there is a native data structure that supports this.  I have never used one.

Comment: I would recommend creating a class, using generic types inside of generic types causes some problems.

Answer (score 2):

How about `HashTable<Key, List<Value>>`?

Answer (score 1):

Just store an array as the value with defined length?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new (non-public) class for your values or use multiple maps (propably slower).

Answer (score 1):

Google's Guava provides a multimap that does this. [Javadoc](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: thanks, handier than writing your own class. and exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as tuples in Java Language, so you can use some of the proposals:

- store an array
- store a List, Set
- store a custom object holding the two values

You also can make a fairly general object: Pair.

```
public Pair<A,B> {
  public Pair(A a, B b) {
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
  }
  public A a() { return a; }
  public B b() { return b; }
}
```